# Why does my binary search use so many comparisons?

Tags: python-3.x, search, binary-search

Here is my code:

```
def binary_search(sortedlist,target,comparisons):
start = 0
end = len(sortedlist) - 1


while(end - start >= 0):
    mid = (start + end)//2
    comparisons += 2
    if(target < sortedlist[mid]):
        comparisons -= 1
        end = mid - 1
    elif(target > sortedlist[mid]):
        start = mid + 1
    else:
        return target, comparisons
return False, comparisons
```

it is basically the same as every other post on here about binary searching but for some reason it uses way too many comparisons.

Here is the code after I fixed it myself

```
from classes import GeneList
## Uncomment the following line to be able to make your own testing Genes
# from classes import Gene, Genome

def binary_search(sortedlist, target, comparisons):
    reducedlist = sortedlist

    while len(reducedlist) > 1:
        mid = len(reducedlist) // 2
        comparisons += 1
        if target < reducedlist[mid]:
            reducedlist = reducedlist[:mid]
        else:
            reducedlist = reducedlist[mid:]

    comparisons += 1
    if reducedlist[0] == target:
        return reducedlist[0], comparisons
    else:
        return False, comparisons


def genetic_similarity_binary(first_genome, second_genome):
    """ This function takes two Genome objects, and returns a GeneList
    and an integer. The GeneList is of all genes that are common
    between first_genome and second_genome, while the integer is
    how many comparisons it took to find all the similar genes.
    Hint: it might pay to define a helper function.
    """
    comparisons = 0
    similar_list = GeneList()
    for target in first_genome:
        result, comparisons = binary_search(second_genome, target, comparisons)
        if result:
            similar_list.append(result)
    return similar_list, comparisons
```

you dont have to do the middle check

Comment: "_So many comparisons_"... in relation to what?

Comment: `>>> binary_search([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],11,0)
(False, 8)`

meaning it takes 8 (!!!!) comparisons to see if 11 is in a list of 10 items

Comment: doesnt that seem like way too many comparisons

Comment: Try binary search on a million items.

Comment: it took 40 comparisons for 1 million

Comment: Does that seem like a lot for a million items? ;-)

Comment: well the computer still says I will fail the assignment because it is too many comparisons

Comment: 8 comparisons in 10 items is normal, since the next highest log2 is 4.

Comment: well if you think so.. I will hand it in and say it was impossible if they fail me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself using far far far fewer comparisons by not checking if it was equal every time. I cant post my code until the assignment is over.

Answer (score 0):

For optimisation purposes, you should check for the termination condition first.
Try this way,

```
def binary_search(sortedlist,target,comparisons):
start = 0
end = len(sortedlist) - 1


while(end - start >= 0):
    mid = (start + end)//2
    comparisons += 2
    if(target == sortedlist[mid]):
        comparisons -= 1
        return target, comparisons
    elif(target > sortedlist[mid]):
        start = mid + 1
    else:
        end = mid - 1
return False, comparisons
```

As upon execution of     `binary_search([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],9,0)`

for your code gives outcome as `(9, 6)` , the above mentioned changes give it as `(9, 5)`

Answer (score 0):

You should search for the third condition in your program first and do the needful in that... Because the third condition is actually the termination condition which should be given first... Try it out.